# Catalina configuration test (catalina.sh configtest)

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, catalina

I have a feeling that there might be something wrong with my Tomcat installation, so I run the following command for sanity check.

```
$TOMCAT_HOME/bin/catalina.sh configtest
```

What does this output mean, or how to go about fixing? Thinking of re-installing Tomcat. OS is Ubuntu.

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar

Jul 01, 2016 12:28:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]

Jul 01, 2016 12:28:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]

Jul 01, 2016 12:28:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]

Jul 01, 2016 12:28:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]

Jul 01, 2016 12:28:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]

Jul 01, 2016 12:28:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]

Jul 01, 2016 12:28:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina initDirs
SEVERE: Cannot find specified temporary folder at /usr/share/tomcat7/temp

Jul 01, 2016 12:28:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Unable to load server configuration from [/usr/share/tomcat7/conf/server.xml]

Configuration error detected!
```

Comment: looks like user by which you are running tomcat doesn't have access to /usr/share/tomcat folder. please check access and run.

Comment: The user has sudo access. The folders with the errors above do indeed not exist. Which is weired because installing Tomcat should have installed the folders.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I was running **Tomcat 7** on **Ubuntu 14.04**. The problem is in the file catalina.properties. In my computer it is located in /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/.

This file has a lot of paths with the variables **${catalina.base}** and **${catalina.home}**. This variables are set in the file catalina.sh. In my computer it is located in /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/.

For some reason the Tomcat 7 is using the **${catalina.home}** wich is **/usr/share/tomcat7/** instead of **${catalina.base}** wich is **/var/lib/tomcat7/**.

To correct this you need to replace the texts below:

- ${catalina.home}/common/classes => ${catalina.base}/common/classes
- ${catalina.home}/common/*.jar => ${catalina.base}/common/*.jar
- ${catalina.home}/server/classes => ${catalina.base}/server/classes
- ${catalina.home}/server/*.jar => ${catalina.base}/server/*.jar
- ${catalina.home}/shared/classes => ${catalina.base}/shared/classes
- ${catalina.home}/shared/*.jar => ${catalina.base}/shared/*.jar

After the replacements, run configtest.sh again to verify.

Comment: This was also [reported as a](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomcat7/+bug/1232258) for tomcat7.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify or add setenv.sh file in bin folder of your tomcat as below

```
export JAVA_HOME="[your java home]"
export CATALINA_BASE="[your tomcat home]"
export CATALINA_HOME=" [ your tomcat home]"
export CATALINA_PID="$CATALINA_BASE/logs/tomcat.pid"
```

This fix work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this after upgrading an Ubuntu 16.04 box to 18.04. As part of the upgrade I merged the Tomcat 8 settings to an existing Tomcat 7 file and forgot to remove these two lines:

```xml
<!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
```

Only the last one was actually causing issues, but if you yank it you will probably want to remove the related comment too.

After making that change, I was able to start Tomcat 8 on the newly upgraded box without issue.